# How can I sort my data in firestore db by the location from the user / nearest geohash?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app written in React Native with Firebase, I have a list of clients in db with their geohashes, now I need to display the list of my clients to the user sorted from the nearest to the furthest. In the docs examples, it says

```
    const q = db.collection('cities')
      .orderBy('geohash')
      .startAt(b[0])
      .endAt(b[1]);
```

however the problem is there is no .collection on my firebase object, I instantiate it like so

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { Firestore, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

let firestore;
if (Constants.manifest?.extra) {
  const {
    FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  } = Constants.manifest.extra;

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firestore = getFirestore();
}
export default firestore as Firestore;
```

in the example, the Firebase db is instantiated like so

```
db = firebase.firestore(app);
```

but there is no firebase object to be imported from "firebase/firestore"

How can I sort my data in db by the location from the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code you started with is using the namespaced syntax of Firebase SDK version 8 and below. Your code however is importing Firebase SDK version 9 or later, which use a new modular syntax.

If we take this v8 code:

```
const q = db.collection('cities')
  .orderBy('geohash')
  .startAt(b[0])
  .endAt(b[1]);
```

The equivalent in v9 would be:

```
import { collection, query, orderBy, startAt, endAt } from "firebase/firestore";
...
const q = query(collection(q, 'cities'), 
  orderBy('geohash'),
  startAt(b[0]),
  endAt(b[1])
);
```

I typically keep the Firebase documentation handy for such code translations, as for example the section on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) contains samples for bth the v8 and v9 syntax side by side. Reading the [v9 upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) is also always a good idea.

Update (2023-07-19): the documentation for [performing geoqueries on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) was just update to include code samples with the modular syntax too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the problem  as below:

**1. Save `geohash` for each client document**

Assume that we have `clients` collection with  documents as below:

```js
{
"hy_uyttdhh":{
firstName:"Satya",
lastName:"Nadella",
geohash:"gbsuv7zt",
coordinate:{
lat:48.669,
lng:-4.32913}
}},
"90kuxddgty":{
firstName:"Sundar",
lastName:"Pichai",
geohash:"gbsuv7z",
coordinate:{
lat:47.669,
lng:-4.70913}
}
},
"iutybdfertyu":{
firstName:"Parag",
lastName:"Agrawal",
geohash:"gbsuv7zs",
coordinate:{
lat:47.669,
lng:-4.70913}
}
}
}
```

**2. Get only clients  location nearby user**

There are 2 factors to determine if the client is a nearby user:

- User current location coordinate
- Boundary radius in mile or km where we expect client is close by

With that in mind, let's write function to only match and return client in the specified boundary.

```js
// Utility library by Firebase team to work with Geolocation
const geofire = require("geofire-common");

const getNearbyClients = async () => {
  const boundaryRadius = 1; // km
  // Reference to clients collection - Syntax should change if you're using Firebase  V9
  const clientsRef = firebase.firestore.collection("clients");
  // Current user location - mocked for sake of simplicity
  const coordinates = { latitude: "48.669", longitude: "-4.32913" };

  const center = [coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude];
  const radiusInM = radius * 1000;

  // Generate geohash boundaries based on center radius, In our context, this will based on current users coordinates
  const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
  // Each item in 'bounds' represents a startAt/endAt pair. We have to issue
  // a separate query for each pair. There can be up to 9 pairs of bounds
  // depending on the overlap, but in most cases, there are 4.

  const matchedBoundariesPromises = bounds.map((b) => {
    let query = clientsRef.orderBy("geohash").startAt(b[0]).endAt(b[1]);
    query = query.get();
    return query;
  });

  // Collect all the query results together into a single list
  const snapshots = await Promise.all(promises);
  let matchingDocs = [];
  snapshots.forEach((snap) => {
    snap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      if (doc.data()) {
        matchingDocs.push(doc.data());
      }
    });
  });
  return matchingDocs;
};
```

**3. Sort matched clients by closest to user**

With nearby clients from firestore, we can sort by  nearest  with this function

```js
const sortClientsByNearest = (clients = [])=>{

// Current user location - mocked for sake of simplicity
 const coordinates = { latitude: "48.669", longitude: "-4.32913" };

 const center = [coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude];
 
const  distanceInKm  =  geofire.distanceBetween([lat,  lng],  center);

return  [...clients].sort(function  (a,  b)  {
const distanceFromA =  geofire.distanceBetween([a.coordinate.lat,  a.coordinate.lng],  center)  
const distanceFromB =  geofire.distanceBetween([b.coordinate.lat,  b.coordinate.lng],  center

return  distanceFromA - distanceFromB

});

}
```